# how to correctly assert struct type in elixir

Tags: testing, elixir, assert

I know you can assert a type struct like this (althought its more a module assert):

```
assert foo.__struct__ == Foo
```

But is there a more elegant way to do this? something like:

```
assert type(foo) == %Foo{}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `=` and pattern matching:

```
assert %Foo{} = foo
```

Comment: @dogbert Wouldn't `==` be more idiomatic instead? `=` will return the evaluation, e.g `%Foo{}` whereas `==` will return `true` In the case of failure, the assertion error will provide better details as to the mismatch.

Comment: @KevinJohnson `==` is incorrect because the fields of `foo` might not match the default fields of `%Foo{}`. `=` is special cased in `assert` to produce helpful error messages on failure.

Comment: There's a reason `=` is called the "match operator". It's the one to use anytime you're pattern matching in a `case`, a `with` or a function head :)

Comment: @dogbert, you're my hero